# Wordpress admin-ajax not working on VPN/access from other country

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have created a plugin for Wordpress in which I'm doing two things:

1. Enabling the user to set some values using the plugin settings page;
2. Enqueue a JavaScript file with admin-ajax call to get those settings and later use on the page;

The JS file does a jQuery/XHR call to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` endpoint with `action=my_action`.

That works totally fine when I test it in my country (Poland)

- I receive a JSON file created from within PHP file.

When I do that from another country (the plugin uses geographical data to show specific content), a call to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=currency` return **a HTML file from my wordpress**.

I've tried to change VPNs, one colleague opened the website in USA and did not see the proper content, another colleague *wgetted* the page from different servers - it worked only for servers in Poland.

I can't find a reason for that in my code, because it always works on normal connection, but stops working in VPN.

I'm attaching the XHR call.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        callback(xhr.responseText);
    } else if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(encodeURI('action=currency'));
```

Of course I have set up all stuff like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_currency', 'currency_all' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_currency', 'currency_all' );
```

I have also tried **disabling all my plugins** - that did not change anything as well.

Comment: _“return a HTML file from my wordpress”_ - which one, what does it contain? Have you checked with your hoster, whether they might have anything in place, that affects these requests before they even get to your WP maybe? What do the access and error logs say?

Comment: That file is the homepage - kind of like that call to _admin-ajax_ caused WordPress to redirect to it.

I've asked an admin to look into the issue, but at first he did not see any obvious reasons for that behaviour.

Did not take a look the logs, hope they'll reveal something.